# Parse text with Stanfor Parser

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I try to parse a text, through [StanfordParser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml) and using oghers' notes I have succeeded to do it. However, for a text like *"the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"* I run the command

```
java -mx6g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -outputFormat xml -file input.txt
```

and it took 130 secs to complete. Is there a way accelerate the process? I am interested only in basic-dependencies xml output. Like this:

```
<dependencies type="basic-dependencies">
  <dep type="root">
    <governor idx="0">ROOT</governor>
    <dependent idx="5">jumped</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="det">
    <governor idx="4">fox</governor>
    <dependent idx="1">the</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="amod">
    <governor idx="4">fox</governor>
    <dependent idx="2">quick</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="amod">
    <governor idx="4">fox</governor>
    <dependent idx="3">brown</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="nsubj">
    <governor idx="5">jumped</governor>
    <dependent idx="4">fox</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="case">
    <governor idx="9">dog</governor>
    <dependent idx="6">over</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="det">
    <governor idx="9">dog</governor>
    <dependent idx="7">the</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="amod">
    <governor idx="9">dog</governor>
    <dependent idx="8">lazy</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="nmod">
    <governor idx="5">jumped</governor>
    <dependent idx="9">dog</dependent>
  </dep>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Are you trying to get POS values for each word in a sentence only?

Comment: Sorry I edited the question. I want a simple xml output with the grammatical structure of the sentence

Comment: Simply loading the models can take a minute or two. Once they are loaded, parsing should be very fast (hundreds of sentences per second)

Comment: @mbatchkarov How Can I load the model, can you explain me plz?

Comment: You don't have to load the model yourself. It's loaded when CoreNLP starts up